# Having trouble fetching data from database for chart in ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, charts, chart.js

I have troubles with loading data from my Azure SQL database to a chart I'm creating using chartJS. I am trying to fetch data from columns "hrPlan", "hrSub" and "hrFact" for the year 2021 from the "workTS" table, but it is currently working incorrectly.
If I try to get values from hrPlan,hrSub or hrFact in a log directly from chart function like this: `console.log("hrPlan=" + hrPlan);` I'm getting the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: hrPlan is not defined`
I think i didn't properly gave data values to my chart function, but I might be wrong.
  Here's how it supposed to look like (all data is hardcoded):[image]
Here's how it looks now:[image]
dbo.workTS:[image]
My code for the workTS model:

```
public class WorkTS
    {
        public string? org { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dt { get; set; }
        public decimal? hrFact { get; set; }
        public decimal? hrPlan { get; set; }
        public decimal? hrReestr { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dtSynchro { get; set; }
        public DateTime? dtMonth { get; set; }
        public decimal? hrSub { get; set; }
        public decimal? hrFactWSub { get; set; }
    }
```

Context:

```
public class AzureDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<WorkTS> WorkTs { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<WorkTS>(builder =>
            {
                builder.HasNoKey();
                builder.ToTable("workTS");
            });
        }

        public AzureDBContext(DbContextOptions<AzureDBContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {            
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("{database connection string}");
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
private readonly AzureDBContext _azdb;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, AzureDBContext azcontext)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _azdb = azcontext;
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> OnGetWorkTSData_MTK()  
        {            
            var plan = _azdb.WorkTs.Where(w => w.org == "ООО \"МТК\"").Where(w => w.dtMonth.Value.Year == 2021).Select(w => w.hrPlan).ToArray();
            var sub = _azdb.WorkTs.Where(w => w.org == "ООО \"МТК\"").Where(w => w.dtMonth.Value.Year == 2021).Select(w => w.hrSub).ToArray();
            var fact = _azdb.WorkTs.Where(w => w.org == "ООО \"МТК\"").Where(w => w.dtMonth.Value.Year == 2021).Select(w => w.hrFact).ToArray();
            return new JsonResult(new { hrPlan = plan, hrSub = sub, hrFact = fact });
        }
```

And finally, code for the chart:

```
            <div>
                <canvas id="workTSChart"></canvas>
            </div>
            <script>console.log("This is first debug line");</script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "Get",
                        url: '@Url.Action("OnGetWorkTSData_MTK","home")',
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {                            
                            var data = response.hrPlan;
                            var data2 = response.hrSub;
                            var data3 = response.hrFact;
                                                        
                            var ctx = document.getElementById("workTSChart");
                            var workTSChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                                type: 'bar',
                                data: {
                                    labels: [
                                        'ООО "МТК"',
                                    ],
                                    datasets: [{
                                        label: 'Plan hours',
                                        data: data,
                                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(161, 221, 239)',
                                        borderColor: 'rgb(161, 221, 239)',
                                    },
                                    {
                                        label: 'Sub hours',
                                        data: data2,
                                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(254, 171, 133)',
                                        borderColor: 'rgb(254, 171, 133)',
                                    },
                                    {
                                        label: 'Fact hours',
                                        data: data3,
                                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(127, 137, 138)',
                                        borderColor: 'rgb(127, 137, 138)',
                                    }]
                                },
                                options: {
                                    responsive: true,
                                    plugins: {
                                        legend: {
                                            position: 'top',
                                        },
                                        title: {
                                            display: true,
                                            text: 'Test chart'
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                            });

                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                            console.log("This is ERROR line");
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Hi @witchgen, your code works well in my project. And it could get the correct value by `response.hrPlan` in ajax success function. What do you mean to log `hrPlan` error?

Comment: @Rena by logging hrPlan error I meant writing the value of hrPlan to log so I can then read it in google chrome's developer log tool. 
Also, I realized my mistake. I should've used `Sum()` instead of `ToArray()` in`var plan = _azdb.WorkTs.Where(w => w.org == "ООО \"МТК\"").Where(w => w.dtMonth.Value.Year == 2021).Select(w => w.hrPlan).ToArray();`
Now I have correct values, but they do not display in my chart for some reason (chart itself is present, but it's empty). How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi @witchgen, you could check [this document](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html). `data` in `datasets` must be an array. I have give a solution below. Please check.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it and now it is working as intended. Also thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the backend is like below, the data you get is just a simple decimal.

```
var plan = _azdb.WorkTs.Where(w => w.org == "ООО \"МТК\"")
                       .Where(w => w.dtMonth.Value.Year == 2021)
                       .Select(w => w.hrPlan)
                       .Sum();
```

`data` in `datasets` should be an array. You need change like below:

```
datasets: [{
    label: 'Plan hours',
    data: [data],    //change here...
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(161, 221, 239)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(161, 221, 239)',
},
{
    label: 'Sub hours',
    data: [data2],     //change here...
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(254, 171, 133)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(254, 171, 133)',
},
{
    label: 'Fact hours',
    data: [data3],    //change here...
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(127, 137, 138)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(127, 137, 138)',
}]
```